# Android OpenGL: Use several Textures for one Animated Sprite

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm programming an Android Game. To reduce the amount of textures that need to be loaded (OpenGL ES 2.0) I've created several spritesheets of size 1024x1024. Some frames of the same animation are on different spritesheets. Now my question is if that is bad for the performance since I have to bind (OpenGL.bind()) a different texture for each animation frame?

Comment: You can safely use 2048x2048 textures for spritesheets

Comment: Hey, I actually don't think that this is true. On some older devices the max texture size is 1024x1024 as far as I can remember!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, changing the texture binding has some performance impact compared to *not* doing it.  How much would probably be best determined by empirical testing.

If you can switch to OpenGL ES 3, you can use a texture array, rather than a texture.

However, if that's not an option, why not simply bind all your sprite sheets at once?  If you have fewer than GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, then you don't need to change the texture binding, just provide some way of letting the shader know to which bound texture it should go.

Comment: Hey Jherico, thank you very much for your answer. Very interesting point you mention! I'm using AndEngine and don't know exactly how the binding is done, maybe you do? The animation-frame changes after a few hundred miliseconds (not in the same draw-cycle), so does it really make a difference to use several textures instead of just one? (Because also in the case of one texture, the texture gets binded in every draw-cycle, am I thinking wrong?)